# Trying to find the probability that there wont be any consecutive numbers in a lottery draw of 1-45

Tags: java, arrays

Trying to find the probability that there wont be any consecutive numbers in a lottery draw of 1-45,cant figure out how to check that the numbers are the not after each other, like 8,9  or 15,14 can anyone help; EDIT. I changed the code so it now puts the values into an int array to sort and compare numbers but now it just outputs zero every time.

```
    import java.util.Random;
    public class Lotto {
        Random rangen = new Random();
        private int result;

        public Lotto()
        {
            result = spin();
        }
        public int getSpin()
        {
            return spin();
        }
        private int spin()
        {
            return rangen.nextInt(45)+1;
        }

    } // this is my spin class with constructors


    import java.util.Arrays;
public class con2
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        int num = 100;
        int count = 0;

        Lotto[] myarray = new Lotto[5]; //an array to hold the lotto spins
        int[] numarray = new int[5];

        for(int i=0; i<myarray.length; i++)//loop to go trough array
        {
            myarray[i] = new Lotto();//fill array with balls or spins
            numarray[i] = myarray[i].getSpin();//fill int array with value of lotto spin
            //Arrays.sort(myarray);//sort the array
        }

        Arrays.sort(numarray);//sort the number array

        for(int i =0; i<num; i++)//monte carlo loop
        {
            for(int z=0;z<numarray.length*2;z++) //loop to go trough the array
            {
               if(numarray[z] == numarray[z+1])
               {
                   count++;//here i want to add 1 to count if number is one larger than position at z
               }
               else if(numarray[z] == numarray[z-1])
               {
                   count++;//here i want to add 1 to count if number is one less than position at z
               }

               else
               {
                   break;//if numbers are the same break out of loop
               }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count/num);

    }
}
```

Comment: Don't add information in comments. Please edit your question and add the necessary information to it, properly formatted.

Comment: First a typo.. your method getspin in con2 is wrong, should be getSpin.

Comment: if(myarray[z].getSpin() == myarray[z+1].getSpin()) will hit an exception, as you try to get the array of z+1, think of check array[5] and compare with array[6] which does not exist.

Comment: (1) This is straightforward though tedious to do analytically. After determining whether the design is with or without replacement (see @Seckin answer) and if "with" whether you want to also detect *equal* numbers, compute p(X2 adjacent X1), p(X3 adjacent X1 or X2 conditional on X2 not adjacent X1), similarly for X4 and X5, and add. I think any question on that would belong on math.SE not here.

Comment: (2) If you do want to do it Monte Carlo, your code is conceptually backwards. You need to do a large number (like a million or so) *different* trials, and count the ones that satisfy the condition. Doing *one* trial and *testing* it repeatedly is a complete waste of time.

Comment: yea it was to be done a million times but because its nested loops its running slow, i just put in 1000 to quicken up the code to see if i could get some sort of output.

Answer (score 0):

Spin method should avoid multiple occurence. At first look it should be changed. You can use collections specifically set.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you mean what is called in standard terminology "selection without replacement". Specifically if the first pick is N then N is "removed" and not possible for any subsequent pick, and similarly for the second and so on. The lotteries I've seen use balls or similar small objects that exit from a drum or chamber, and thus are selected without replacement. If a lottery did in fact use a spinner that would more naturally select "with replacement".

Comment: In case of "selection without replacement" I think below code will at least generate required number of unique balls;                                                Random generateNumber=new Random();
        
         Set<Integer>numberDrawn= new HashSet<Integer>();
         
        do{
                    numberDrawn.add(generateNumber.nextInt(45)+1);       

        }   while(numberDrawn.size()<6);